# How to have Safe Remove icon in the system tray in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, notification-area, safely-remove-hardware

In my installation there is no Safe Remove icon in the system tray. It is not hidden, simply there is no such icon. (I checked in "Notifications & actions" and there is no such icon in the list, and even switched on "Always show all icons...",) no traces...

I have two USB drives plugged in... 
Both drive's policy is set to "Best performance" and not "Quick removal"

There is no eject in the context menu when I right click on them.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Do you see the drives in "Devices and Printers" (not "Device Manager"): https://ptpb.pw/rrdZ.PNG ; If so can you attach a screenshot like mine? (Double click on them and switch to the "Hardware" tab)

Comment: See my edit, added  picture

Comment: Can you check what's the `Removal policy` of the `USB Mass Storage Device` listed there? : https://ptpb.pw/KkAD.PNG ; Also, is the drive connected directly to a USB port on the motherboard or is there any hub or so in between?

Comment: Btw, it's normal that you don't see "Eject" when you right click on it, because it's probably a `Basic` disk (typical for portable HDD) instead of a `Removable` disk (typical for thumb drive), but that doesn't affect whether it shows up with the icon. Also, it doesn't really matter whether you pick `Quick removal` or `Better performance` either.

Comment: Apart from `Removal policy`, also check `Safe removal required`.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this article here, it's pretty explanatory](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/restore-missing-or-disappeared-safely-remove-hardware-icon/)

TL;DR:
beside the obvious hidden notification selection that you mentioned,

- try: winLKey+R and run this command `rundll32.exe
  shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll`
- Open My Computer ->Right click on the USBdrive->Properties->Hardware tab and select the removable drive from the list ->Click the Properties button ->Click on the Policies tab->Change the option from “Optimize for quick removal” to “Optimize for performance” ->press OK.
- try [USB Disk Ejector](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/usb-disk-ejector-is-a-free-alternative-to-usb-safely-remove/)

Comment: Thanks. I've read that already. Also I wrote in my question in advance "Both drive's policy is set to 'Best performance' and not 'Quick removal'"